# No entiendo bien cuando la clase hija hereda los métodos de la clase padre

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

En el libro la clase hija se puse self, nombre, pero no puedo poner un segundo self, después no entiendo porque abajo ponen 4, a sacarlo ya no recopila, intente poner self.4 = 4, pero no puedo recopilado, intente cambiarlo a una palabra pero tampoco se puede. Tampoco entiendo el Animal.**init** y no ponen el super().

```
#!C:\python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

class Animal:
  """Clase base para mostrar la herencia"""

  def __init__(self, nombre, patas):
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.patas = patas

  def saluda(self):
    print("El animal llamado " + str(self.nombre) + " saluda")

class Perro(Animal):
  """Clase hija para mostrar la herencia"""

  def __init__(self, nombre):
    Animal.__init__(self, nombre, 4)
    self.sonido = "Guau"

  def ladra(self):
    print(self.sonido)

mi_mascota = Perro("Chucho")

mi_mascota.saluda()

mi_mascota.ladra()
input()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando una clase hereda otra, hereda todos sus métodos y atributos. Es decir, la instancia de la clase Perro (mi_mascota), que realizas en la siguiente línea:

> ```
> mi_mascota = Perro("Chucho")
> ```

Coge los atributos de *nombre*, *patas* y el método *saluda* que tiene *Animal*. Es como si internamente se copiara y pegara, y al final *Perro* sería algo parecido a esto:

```
class Perro(Animal):
  """Clase hija para mostrar la herencia"""

  def __init__(self, nombre):
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.patas = 4
    self.sonido = "Guau"

  def ladra(self):
    print(self.sonido)

  def saluda(self):
    print("El animal llamado " + str(self.nombre) + " saluda")
```

¿Por qué no puedes poner `self.4`? Porque *4* es solo el valor de `self.patas`. Prueba a poner `self.patas`, y ahí tendrás el valor *4* que se le pasa al constructor.

Prueba a poner un método dentro de la clase *Perro*, que sea de la siguiente forma:

```
  def get_patas(self):
    return self.patas
```

Y antes del `input()` final, pon lo siguiente:

```
print(f"Mi mascota tiene {mi_mascota.get_patas()} patas.")
```

Lo que estarías haciendo ahí sería llamar al método get_patas, que te devuelve el valor de *patas*, y lo estarías mostrando por pantalla.

> **Tampoco entiendo el Animal.init y no ponen el super().**

En este ejemplo, `Animal.__init__()` y `super().__init__()` tendrían la misma función, podrías poner `super` en lugar de *Animal*.

Pero imagina que *Perro* hereda más de una clase, por ejemplo *Animal* y *Propietario*. La cabecera de la clase quedaría algo como:

```
class Perro(Propietario, Animal):
```

Si pusieras `self.__init__()`, estarías invocando a *Propietario*, y no a *Animal*, porque es la que primero se hereda. Pongamos como ejemplo que propietario es de la siguiente forma:

```
class Propietario:
def __init__(self, nombre):
    self.nombre_propietario = nombre
```

La clase Perro, por lo tanto, podría tener de constructor la siguiente forma:

```
class Perro(Propietario, Animal):
  """Clase hija para mostrar la herencia"""

  def __init__(self, nombre, nombre_propietario):
    Animal.__init__(self, nombre, 4)
    super().__init__(nombre_propietario)
    self.sonido = "Guau"
    print(Perro.__mro__)
```

Fíjate que aquí he puesto `super()`, pero podrías cambiarlo por *Propietario*. Le he puesto un nuevo parámetro al constructor para darle el nombre del propietario. Al instanciar nuestra clase *Perro*, habría que ponerle un atributo más: `mi_mascota = Perro("Chucho", "Laura")`.
¿Y qué hace la última línea `print(Perro.__mro__)`? Prueba a ponerla y a imprimirla, y te mostrará el orden de la jerarquía de herencia.

Comment: No encuentro con que funcion debo unir para imprimir a print(Perro.__mro__), ya lo puse con def hola(self), pero nada, como haria para imprimirlo ???

Comment: Cuando tú creas un objeto, es decir, cuando creas una instancia de la clase, de manera **automática** se ejecuta el método constructor, es decir el `__init__(self)`. Cuando haces esto:
`mi_mascota = Perro("Chucho")`
se ejecuta todo lo que hay dentro de `__init__()`, así que de esa forma es como de manera también automática se ejecuta `print(Perro.__mro__)`.

Comment: me sale asi (<class '__main__.Perro'>, <class '__main__.Propietario'>, <class '__main__.Animal'>, <class 'object'>)
El animal llamado Chucho saluda
Guau

Comment: Perfecto. Esto: `<class 'main.Perro'>, <class 'main.Propietario'>, <class 'main.Animal'>, <class 'object'>`, corresponde a print(Perro.__mro__). Ahí te enseña el orden de la jerarquía de herencia. Primero la clase Perro, luego Propietario, luego Animal, y por último la superclase object de Python, de lo que todo desciende. Si tienes duda con alguna cosa en concreto, créate un archivo con una cosa muy puntual, y así vas entendiendo de dónde sale una cosa u otra. Por ejemplo, puedes crear un archivo solo con una clase, con un método constructor, y luego desde fuera, crear un objeto de la clase.